# How to Save Slug Automatic in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Here is my code for saving slug automatically. But it doesn't work and I don't know why! I can't be totally wrong. Help me to get out.

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify



class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False,unique=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # new
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But in django Admin panel I have to save slug manually But I want to save it automatically.

Help me to understand this. Thanks Good People.

Comment: hide `slug` field from Django Admin

Comment: Set `null=True` on your `SlugField` and the slug should save automatically because of your overridden `save()` method.

Comment: There was another resource where I saw the wrote an another python file in main project folder named utils.py. What does it do?

Comment: After setting null = True problem not solved. It's Shows as a required field.

Comment: Try including `blank=True` also

Comment: Yeah. It works fine.

So what you suggest: this is a good way to do it I mean generating slugs or there are any better solutions.  :)

Comment: I think your solution is ok. I posted my answer. Could you vote as correct please? Thanks

Comment: That is not my answer haha ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`exclude`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude) the **`slug`** field from Django Admin by creating a ModelAdmin class as below,

```
# admin.py

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('slug',)


admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

Comment: wow! 
So for slug field null was false. So it was required field by default. So what's happen after I exclude it to admin.py ?

Comment: form validation only for *present* fields, if you exclude the fields the validation check also excluded

Comment: Another Thing I want to ask you.... I saw some resources, where I saw they making a python file alongside settings.py file named utils.py to generate Slug. What's the benefit to using it. 

and the way I did, is it good way to do it or there are other options?

Comment: @ApAnik, I think it is better not to use utils.py if it your code for slug will be short. Alterntively, you can use AutoSlug and have clean code without worrying about uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

So, set `null=True` and add `blank=True`.

```
slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
```